# Least cost path barrier (R) (gdistance)

Tags: r, cost-path

I'm trying to create a barrier (rivers) that can't be crossed by the least cost path.

I've created a transition layer using "areas" which contains the transition values on land, and on rivers. However, the barrier has a 'buffer' around it, with increasing values, instead of being a discrete barrier.

Cost raster and transition layer
[image: cost raster]
[image: Transition layer]
As can be seen, there's a 'buffer' around the barrier in the transition layer.

Any ideas on how to create a discrete boundary? preferably with the barrier as a value 1000, with everywhere else a value of 1.

code:
`library(gdistance)
    ## Create cost surface where "land" exists in the middle
    cost <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
               xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm")
    cost[] <- 10
    cost[cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50:55,20:80)] <- 1000
    costf <- asFactor(cost < 100)
    ## Produce transition matrices, and correct because 8 directions
    trCost <- transition(costf, "areas", directions=16)
    trCost1 <- geoCorrection(trCost[[2]], type="c")
    plot(cost)
    plot(raster(trCost[[1]]))`

Comment: You should give some reproducible code and data if you want any help. so that we can try to help you. However, I suppose that this "buffer" area is normal because you trying to see path. Depending on your starting and arriving positions, you have a small probability to walk along the barrier.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Reproducible code added. 

I didn't think about that actually. I guess this stops the line from 'hugging' the barrier, instead of being diverted earlier on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options to create this type of barrier by using the transitionFuntion argument in the transition function strategically. This should cover 99% of the cases. Set the conductance value to 0 to make sure the path does not cross the river at all. (To make the river 100 times more costly than land, use a small conductance value instead: 0.01.)

Here we go.

```
library(gdistance)
```

Create cost surface setting land to a conductance of 10.

```
cost <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
           xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm")
cost[] <- 10
```

Set origin and goal cells for testing

```
origin <- c(50, 1)
goal <- c(50, 100)
```

## Option 1 - transitionFunction = mean

```
cc1 <- cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50:55,20:80)
cost1 <- cost
cost1[cc1] <- 0 
trCost1 <- transition(cost1, transitionFunction = mean, 16)
trCost1 <- geoCorrection(trCost1, type="c")
```

Check if Option 1 has worked

```
plot(raster(trCost1))
sPath1 <- shortestPath(trCost1, origin, goal, output="SpatialLines")
lines(sPath1)
```

## Option 2 - transitionFunction = min

Option 1 will not work with rivers that are only one cell broad. If this is a problem, Option 2 is an alternative.

```
cc2 <- cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50,20:80)
cost2 <- cost
cost2[cc2] <- 0 
trCost2 <- transition(cost2, transitionFunction = min, 8)
trCost2 <- geoCorrection(trCost2, type="c")
```

Don't use 16 directions for Option 2, as this will make it possible to jump over the barrier (chess knight movement)!

Check if Option 2 has worked.

```
plot(raster(trCost2))
sPath2 <- shortestPath(trCost2, origin, goal, output="SpatialLines")
lines(sPath2)
```